# PHP - Unable to set Shipping Address for PayPal REST API

Tags: php, paypal

I was wondering to set Shipping address for my customer from my website... But the code I've found in docs and from SO is not working for me somehow.. can anybody help me what's the issue is?

**My Code :**

```
use PayPal\Rest\ApiContext;
use PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential;
use PayPal\Api\Amount;
use PayPal\Api\Details;
use PayPal\Api\Item;
use PayPal\Api\ItemList;
use PayPal\Api\Payer;
use PayPal\Api\Payment;
use PayPal\Api\RedirectUrls;
use PayPal\Api\ExecutePayment;
use PayPal\Api\PaymentExecution;
use PayPal\Api\Transaction;
use PayPal\Api\ShippingAddress;               



$Itemssss = new ItemList();
               $shipping_address = new ShippingAddress();
               $shipping_address->setCity('bahawalpur');
               $shipping_address->setCountryCode('PK');
               $shipping_address->setPostalCode('63100');
               $shipping_address->setLine1('Abdullah house street no 3');
               $shipping_address->setState('punjab');
               $shipping_address->setRecipientName('saqlain');

               $Itemssss->setShippingAddress($shipping_address);
```

and here is the address what it shows when I am redirected to paypal

[image]

Comment: maybe `paypal` not dealing in `Bahawalpur`

Comment: is it possible? does he verifies addreses?

Comment: check this https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/formbasics/#auto-fill-forms-with-html-variables

Comment: I have changed address to a valid address supported by Paypal.. but still no progress :(